# Grails last login field not updating

Tags: grails, groovy

This is my entity class and login code. My last login remains null in db with no exception thrown. i tried logging the hibernate sql statements. It seem that the update statement isn't executed...

entity:

```
class Users {
  static hasMany = [farm:Farms,report:Reports,reportMessage:ReportMessages,notifications:Notifications]

  String userName 
  String Password
  Date lastLogin
  String userImage

  static constraints = {
    userName (blank:false, unique:true)
    Password (blank:false)
    userImage (blank:false)
    lastLogin (nullable:true, blank:true)
  }
}
```

login code

```
def login(user)
{
    def status = false;        
    Users u = user;
    Users users = Users.findByUserName(u.userName)
    PasswordCodec pwd = new PasswordCodec();
    u.Password = pwd.encode(u.Password)
    if (users !=null && u.Password.equals(users.Password))
    {
        u.lastLogin = new Date()
        u.save()
        status = true
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `u.save()` with `u.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)` and see if that throws an error.

Comment: that makes no diff in grails!

Comment: If the passed in `user` is a domain object you got out of the database then yes I would agree that it wouldn't make a difference.  Your code isn't working and my suggestions are what I would do to identify the problem.  Try removing all of the code except the setting of the date and saving.  Next I would look at the mapping and the database table to ensure they are setup correctly (I'd assume they are since you're not getting an error, but it's a place to look).

Comment: Try changing the constraint on lastLogin to just "nullable:true"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are assigning the `lastLogin` date to the command object passed with the request. The stored domain object seems not to be updated:

```
u.lastLogin = new Date()
u.save()
```

should be replaced by

```
users.lastLogin = new Date()
users.save()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 :-) nicely spotted amongst a forest of badly-named variables and properties!

Answer (score 2):

Tim's right - the class and variable names are very distracting. Domain class names should be singular. If you insist on using the silly plural table name convention from Rails, you can configure that in the mapping block:

```
class User {
   ...
   static mapping = {
      table 'users'
   }
}
```

Using a local plural variable for a `Users` instance is confusing too - `Users users = ...` is misleading since it implies that `users` is a collection of possibly more than one instance.

I'd advise you to stop working so hard though and use Spring Security Core or Shiro. Rolling your own security is risky and takes time away from implementing the real features of your site.